# Is this a closed subset of M_n(R)

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the Matrices in $GL_m(R)$ such that $A^n=I$ for some n a closed subset of $M_m(R)$? n is not fixed.

Comment: This question is ambiguous: is $n$ fixed or not? For a fixed $n$ the answer is yes.

Comment: Of couse not....For n fixed it is easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not closed. The set of such matrices has two (separated) components: those with determinant $1$ and those with determinant $-1$. These sets are intersection of the given set with two (separated) closed subsets of $GL_m$. So the given set is closed iff both of those subsets are closed.

For $m=2$, the set $A$ of those matrices with determinant $1$ is a subset of the rotation group $SO_2$ on the plane.

Since $SO_2$ is isomorphic to $S^1$, $A$ is isomorphic to the set of complex roots of $1$. The latter subset is not closed in $S^1$, hence $A$ is not closed in $SO_2$.

Comment: Brilliantly done thanks...:D